# Cannot save image from Bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap, fileoutputstream, bitmapdrawable

I get a warning stating that the result of `cachePath.createNewFile();` is ignored. Otherwise the following code does not save an image to my phone. What can I do?

```
holder.messageImage.setOnLongClickListener(v -> {
            v.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.VIRTUAL_KEY);

            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) holder.messageImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

            File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File cachePath = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/Camera/image.jpg");

            try {
                FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(cachePath);
                bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ostream);
                ostream.close();
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Image saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.w(getClass().toString(), e);
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Failed saving image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            return false;
        });
```

**I download the image from my back end this way:**

```
private void downloadMessageImage(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<>(ParseConstants.CLASS_YEET);
        query.whereEqualTo(ParseConstants.KEY_OBJECT_ID, mYeets.get(position).getObjectId());
        query.findInBackground((user, e) -> {
            if (e == null) for (ParseObject userObject : user) {

                if (userObject.getParseFile("image") != null) {
                    String imageURL = userObject.getParseFile("image").getUrl();
                    /*Log.w(getClass().toString(), imageURL);*/

                   if (imageURL != null) {

                        holder.messageImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        Picasso.with(mContext)
                                .load(imageURL)
                                .placeholder(R.color.placeholderblue)
                                .into(holder.messageImage);

                    } else {
                        holder.messageImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

The bitmap certainly does not exist: `android.graphics.Bitmap@12d9cc4`

Comment: `cachePath.createNewFile();` Remove that statement. It's useless.

Comment: Do you have any exception? If yes post the logcat.

Comment: There's not exception.

Comment: Put a Toast in that catch block. You should inform the user if there is one.

Comment: `following code does not save an image to my phone`. How did you check that is does not?

Comment: The toast indicates that that image is saved successfully but I cannot find it in my phone DCIM Camera directory. The thing is, the image is coming from a view holder in my RecyclerAdapter, which is being downloaded from my back end. Maybe this will impact it?

Answer (score 0):

to save an image I use the following code:

```
try {
       signature.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
       Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(signature.getDrawingCache());
       // Define params for save
       File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Cassiopea/momomorez/" + File.separator + "signature.png");
       f.createNewFile();
       FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
       os = new FileOutputStream(f);
       //compress to specified format (PNG), quality - which is ignored for PNG, and out stream
       bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, os);
       Toast.makeText(mContext, "Saving image OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       os.close();
} 
catch (Exception e) {
       Log.v("Gestures", e.getMessage());
       e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Use this code to save a pattern in an image within an established folder.

Comment: This didn't work. The ``Saving image OK`` toast was shown but I can't find the image anywhere on my phone.

Comment: Is a GestureOverlayView I use it to create an image of a signature made by tablet

Comment: is present <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> in the AndroidManifest.xml